# How do I add values in the drop down of my tkinter combo box?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am creating a multi-row GUI for booking details.
I have already imported the tkinter and written code for the other text fields but I cannot put values in my combo box!
I get it to show up in the window but it has no values in it!!
Where am I going wrong?

I have tried using another code but when I ran the code, two windows popped up - one for the total price, flight host, etc and one for the combo box

```
        tk.Label(form_frame, text= "Go To", font=('arial', 10),
                width=20, anchor="e", bd=1,
                pady=10, padx=10).grid(row=4, column=0)
        comboExample = ttk.Combobox( 
                                    values=[
                                            "Customer Details", 
                                            "Flight Details"])
        combo_prod_cat = ttk.Combobox(form_frame, state="normal", width=10)
        combo_prod_cat.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
```

I am expecting the window to pop up as this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eqUS.jpg

but with the values Customer Details and Flight Details in the drop down

Comment: There are two comboboxes in the above code, and you only called `grid` on the 2nd one which has no value. Perhaps try to `grid` the first one `comboExample` also?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need 'OptionMenu()' instead of 'ComboBox()'.
A short example below:

```
# your options
values = ['-', 'Customer Details', 'Flight Details']

# variable which holds the current selected option. It none selected it's '-'.
dd_option = StringVar(form_frame)
dd_option.set('-')

dropdown = OptionMenu(form_frame, dd_option, *values)
dropdown.grid(<your element placement>)
```

To trace the selection you can use s.th. like this:

```
def value_changed(*args):
    # exmaple
    print(dd_option.get())

dd_option.trace('w', value_change)
```

Here is a full example of option menu:
https://pythonspot.com/tk-dropdown-example/

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
It is for an assignment that requires the use of combo box unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the values parameter.

```
chosen_var = StringVar(form_frame)
combo_prod_cat = ttk.Combobox(form_frame, state="normal", width=10, values=["Choose", "Customer Details", "Flight Details"], textvariable=chosen_var, width=20)
combo_prod_cat.current(0)
combo_prod_cat.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
```

That works on my machine. And have you noticed that you're not specifying values in `combo_prod_cat`? Only in `comboExample`?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh and this link might help - its a tkinter documentation pdf. It's a bit dry, but *very* useful and overly thorough - So its perfect for reference.